# Thrown Error in Terminal (Mac) Question: npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

I am trying to install react in my terminal - **$ npx create-react-app my-app**. After entering command, I received this error:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_transform.js'

I have searched high and low trying to understand what this is trying to tell me, with very little luck. I have:

- removed manually and re-installed node/npm (macOS pkg).
- enter **$node -v** returns the correct version and entered **$npm -v** returns correct version.
- was told to update the latest version of npm with **$sudo npm install -g npm@latest** and it updated with the new version.
- checked **$echo $PATH** and appears to be correct in /usr/local/lib.
- made sure to **$npm uninstall -g create-react-app** as well just to make sure there wasn't something I missed.
- cleared cache with **--force**.
- last thing tried was to **$npm init react-app my-app** in a test folder and terminal told me to install create-react-app and entered y. It did install create-react-app but in my test folder and was missing .gitignore file but it did look to have downloaded the rest.

I have removed the create-react-app manually and tried again with **$npx create-react-app my-app** and the error was thrown again.

Is it fine the way of trying to **$npm init react-app my-app** and install create-react-app that way? - Does create-react-app need to be in /usr/local/lib? - How do I get a .gitignore file into it, if I can?

Any help or recommendations is so greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Nothing you have described points to a problem, but you omitted everything about the versions you are using.  "Does create-react-app need to be in /usr/local/lib?" no. "how do I get a .gitignore file into it, if I can?" this is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @possum the versions I am using are the most current LTS version, v20.11.1 for node and npm was updated to 10.5.0. I am learning and I am not sure if it is necessary to install react by "npx create-react-app my-app", or if it doesn't matter to install with trying "npm init react-app my-app". If it's best to install with"npx create-react-app my-app", then I am not sure what to do to resolve the issue of the error that keeps appearing (stated in beginning of the question). For .gitignore file, I wasn't sure if it was necessary to have and if it is, is it something I can add after.